Connect to an external database over HTTP Proxy with .NET Core
My requirement is to connect to an external SQL Server database from my organization network. My .NET Core application is hosted in Openshift Container and it has to go through an internal Bluecoat Web Proxy -> Firewall to external database.
Right now my approach is to create a TCP tunnel to this external database and then connect to the database with the below connection string.
var connectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=false;User ID=username;Password=sqlPassword;TrustServerCertificate=true;";

TCP tunnel creation was successful but when I tried to connect to the database, I get a network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. (more of a generic error)
When I check the logs on both sides I can see the TCP tunnel creation success but from the external side, I see [RST, ACK] (Reset Acknowledgement) right after that.
I want to know if the current approach I'm trying is correct or if there is another way to do this in a better way.
This here is my TCP tunnel creation and SQL connect code:
// Connect to the proxy server
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(proxyIP, proxyPort);
NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    
// Create the proxy authentication header
string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{proxyUsername}:{proxyPassword}"));
string connectRequest = $"CONNECT {targetHost}:{targetPort} HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                        $"Host: {targetHost}:{targetPort}\r\n" +
                        $"Proxy-Authorization: Basic {authInfo}\r\n" +
                        "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
    
// Send the CONNECT request to the proxy
byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connectRequest);
await networkStream.WriteAsync(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    
// Read the response from the proxy
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
string responseLine = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    
if (!responseLine.Contains("200 Connection established"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to establish a connection with the target server.");
    return;
}
    
// At this point, the tunnel is established
Console.WriteLine("Tunnel established");

// from here I'm connecting to my database
var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

// This line throws the error
con.Open();   

I have also tried the below code to read from the SQL server. But I don't see any response. Is this a correct approach?
So, for data reading can I use the below? I tried it but I don't see any response.
byte[] sqlQueryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblTest");
networkStream.Write(sqlQueryBytes, 0, sqlQueryBytes.Length);
    
byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
Console.WriteLine(response);


Where did you get the impression this would work? (because it won't: modern versions of SQL Server and the SQL Server client do attempt to verify server identity - your SqlConnection will know that the machine it's talking to really isn't 127.0.0.1.

@Dai But wouldn't my 1433 port traffic should flow through the tunnel that I created?

Even if you were setting this up correctly I'd be very surprised if the idea worked through a BCSI proxy, because enterprise-grade appliances tend to do deep inspection and would reject anything that doesn't look like a HTTP stream. You aren't setting this up correctly because there's no connection between the SqlConnection instance and the upstream server. Normally you'd open a server socket locally (to which the SqlConnection would connect as a client) and then its Accept handler is what opens the upstream connection through the proxy to the origin server and shuffles bytes between them.

I have added another solution that I tried. But that doesn't return anything at all and no errors. Is this a valid way of doing this?

Does anyone have an opinion on this issue?

The additional snippet is also not a valid way of doing this. SQL Server doesn't use a text-based communications protocol that's semi-human-understandable like POP3 or SMTP, it's a binary protocol called MS-TDS; Microsoft Tabular Data Stream.

Do you think creating a SSH tunnel would solve this? @AlwaysLearning

This was solved by creating a TcpListener, and the listener will create the TCP tunnel. So from the code, we access localhost:(listnerPort). Below is the code sample that worked for me,
Create BackgroundService for listener,
public class TcpTunnelService : BackgroundService
{
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
string proxyAddress = "11.22.22.11";
int proxyPort = 8081;

string sqlAddress = "11.22.33.44";
int sqlPort = 1433;

var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        listener.Start();

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            _ = HandleClientAsync(client, proxyAddress, proxyPort, sqlAddress, sqlPort);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleClientAsync(TcpClient client, string proxyAddress, int proxyPort, string sqlAddress, int sqlPort)
    {
using(client)
{
 TcpClient proxyClient = new TcpClent();
 await proxyClient.ConnectAsync(proxyAddress, proxyPort);

 using(proxyClent)
 using(NetworkStream cs = clent.Stream())
 using(NetworkStream ps = proxyClent.GetStream())
 {
  string proxyCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{yourProxyUserName}:{yourProxyPassword}"));
  
  StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ps);
  w.WriteLine($"CONNECT {sqlAddress}:{sqlPort} HTTP/1.1");
  w.WriteLine($"Host: {sqlAddress}:{sqlPort}");
  w.WriteLine($"Proxy-Authorization: Basic {proxyCredentials}");
  w.WriteLine("Connection: keep-alive");
  w.WriteLine();
  w.Flush();

  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ps);
  string res = await sr.ReadLineAsync();

  if(!res.Contains("200 Connection established"))
  {
   //errror
   return;
  }
  else
  {
   //success
  }

  Task cToProxy = RelayDataAsync(cs, ps);
  Task pToClient = RelayDataAsync(ps, cs);

  await Task.WhenAny(cToProxy, pToClient);
 }
}
}
 private async Task RelayDataAsync(NetworkStream source, NetworkStream dest)
 {
  byte[] buf= new byte[8192];
  int bytesRead;

  while(bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
   await dest.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytesRead);
  }
 }
}

Then register service like below,
services.AddHostedService<TcpListenerService>();

Connection string has to be like below,
"Data Source=localhost,8888; Initial Catelog= ....."

